# How do I find my 1N 4007 diodes?

Tags: components

I am a beginner to Arduino, and a relative beginner to electronics in general. I have the official Arduino Starter Kit. I've looked through my bag of components looking for a black diode but was unable to find it among all of the LEDS & the other black components.

Comment: Maybe show us some pictures of what you *do* have...

Comment: What is Google?

Answer (score 1):

While the [ArduinoStarterKit page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoStarterKit) at arduino.cc lists “5 Diodes [1N4007]” as part of it, and has a picture where 5 diodes apparently appear slightly left of center in the top row, several other pictures that come up in a [google images search for *official Arduino Starter Kit*](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1400&bih=896&q=official+Arduino+Starter+Kit&oq=official+Arduino+Starter+Kit&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24k1l3.1366.1366.0.3233.2.2.0.0.0.0.88.88.1.1.0....0...1ac..64.img..1.1.87.0.eMHm1WmRzhk#imgrc=IBZ9ux6HxlSEfM:) apparently don't show the diodes.  Eg, as at [arduino starter kit](http://www.arduino.org/products/kits/arduino-starter-kit).  But [4 Best Starter Kits for Arduino Beginners](http://www.nbcdaily.com/4-best-starter-kits-for-arduino-beginners/3883/) does show them.

Note, unless you are working with medium to high AC voltages (eg above 50 V) you can substitute 1N4001 - 1N4004 which have lower PIV ratings but also slightly lower forward voltage drop.  For many beginning projects, [1N4148 signal diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N4148_signal_diode) will be adequate and perhaps less expensive.

Answer (score 1):

1N4007 are usually black with a white stipe indicating the cathode. Use a magnifying glass and you should be able to see the marking.

Answer (score 1):

They are stuck next to a string of resistors.

[image: Diodes and resistors]

Answer (score 1):

This is image of 1N4007 diodes. I think now you can find them easily.

[image]